# Internal Storage in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, relational-database, hdfs, sqoop

I am new to Hadoop and have a question regarding internal storage of it. As I know, everything in HDFS is stored as Key/Value pairs. Now, with the help of Yarn, different technologies have emerged to import different types of data like Streams and Data from RDMBSs (using Sqoop). How these kind of data are stored internally in HDFS? Are for example the rows of a relational table somehow converted to Key/Value pairs? Even using Hive and Hcatalog you can Create tables and load data to them. How all of these are done internally in hadoop?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that data is stored as key/value on the HDFS. It is stored as normal files are stored in an unstructured format. However, when you run a MapReduce job, the data is treated as key,value pairs based on the InputFormat that you chose. For example, if the input format is TextInputFormat, the key will be the position of the data in the file, while the value will be a line of data, while when you use a different input format, the key,value assignment would be different.